# Sql Server 2012 weird issue with locking (UPDLOCK)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, locking

In my .NET web application I have a routine which is divided into two parts. Most of the time both parts of the routine are called one after another,

```
var result = Method1(someParams);
var finalResult = Method2(result);
```

they are divided into two because one can be and sometimes is called without calling the other one. Both of those methods internally query a data from a table `Table1`. As parameters are different for two methods above, the select query they run are also different, but I want to lock the row which will get selected by any of those two methods, so that the other won't be able to select it before the one that queried it first is complete. As the data that gets selected, should be updated afterwards, the select query utilizes `UPDLOCK` keyword, but as mentioned above, two of those methods have different parameters so what I did to achieve the best result was following:

`Method1` executes this query

```
SELECT Id FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = @Param1 AND Column2 = @Param2
```

then it executes the following query with selected `Id` to get all the columns.

```
SELECT Id, Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4 
FROM Table1 WITH ( UPDLOCK, INDEX ( PK_Table1 ) )
WHERE Id = @IdParam
```

`Method2` executes second query ONLY (as Id is passed to it from outside). So whenever `Method1` and `Method2` will be called at the same time (for the same record), one will wait for another as before updating the data they will have to acquire `UPDLOCK` for the same row.

I also included `INDEX(PK_Table1) --(Primary Key)` in the query, because I thought the database was switching indexes for some reason.

The problem that I run into occasionally is that, locking mechanisms does not work correctly when those methods are called 4 or more times at the same time (for the same row). I see results that directly imply that the records are not being locked when selected. Thing I do in these cases is just alter the procedures containing above queries (without modified the query, which would probably just force recompile it). I can see that altering helps because I have a test written which checks if above mention mechanism works correctly or not. After I detect that there is a problem and before I alter the procedure I run the test which yields the result that is wrong and should not have occurred if locking was working properly, after altering those two procedures I run tests again and everything is OK.

This case emerges once in 1-2 months but really does some damage before it gets detected and fixed. It has happened 4 times already. When it happened the 3rd time I added the `INDEX(PK_Table1)` in the `WITH` clause and I was convinced that this was a fix, but it happened again.

Comment: I'm interested to try and see if I can reproduce this. But I have to suspect it's less likely that it's a SQL Server locking bug than that the SPs are being called somewhere without a transaction.

I take it from your last reply to my bad answer that you're opening and commiting transactions in your .net code? If so, have you considered moving the transaction management into the SP code?

Comment: Can I ask the build of SQL 2012 you're on, what compatibility level the database is set to, whether or not readcommittedsnapshot and/or snapshot isolation are enabled on the database, and what isolation level your transactions use?

Comment: yes the application is running in .NET environment. To be exact it is ASP.NET MVC 4. those sql procedures are ran just from Method1 and Method2, no one else even cares about their existence, I highly doubt that the problem is with opening/commiting transactions. (at .NET side)

Comment: Here is @@Version string  --   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU5) (KB3180915) - 11.0.6544.0 (X64)   Aug 29 2016 14:00:09   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor). --  Compatibility level is 110, Read Committed Snapshot is enabled. for above queries I am not specifing custom isolation level, so it should be the default one.

Comment: Well, I've only got access to SP1, but I've hammered it with two SPs running 20k times in 20 threads each, with a recompile of both every 5 seconds, and the lock rows count for the session in sys.dm_tran_locks shows the expected 4 after every udplock select (which then updates the row and commits). And the waiting tasks is consistently ~40, so the locking is definitely working. (Continues.)

Comment: I know that's not conclusive by any means, but I can only think the app-based transaction is the most likely cause--even though a recompile resolving things suggests otherwise. Either way, proving a .net or SQL bug will be near impossible, so perhaps the best you can do for now is to check @@trancount before the updlock select, and if it's 0 then have the app recompile the SPs and retry? Or check for the expected locks in sys.dm_tran_locks?

Comment: Globally speaking those procedures are the main part of app, so they will always be more than one concurrent queries executing at once, I think the best solution here can be WITH RECOMPILE hint for the procedure itself, but I'm afraid that It will just exhaust the CPU resources.

Comment: Yeah Locking is working perfectly (99.99% of the time), the test that I run after discovering that something messed up, runs 100 of those quires in parallel on 10 threads (100 on each thread). When something messes up and I run the test I get really bad results, ones that I'm using UPDLOCK to get rid of for. But after altering/recompiling and running test again locks are handled perfectly. but after a month or two this problem emerges again.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't assume WITH RECOMPILE will do the trick, as I would think an ALTER does more. (Which I didn't consider when suggesting you have the app do a recompile--there would be ways to generate the SP code and ALTER from the app as well.) And even if ALTER has worked so far, it might not always work. If it were my app, I would be looking at alternate locking mechanisms, or verifying that the select has locked something as expected--checking @@trancount before the select might not even be reliable enough. Best of luck whatever you end up doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

(Update: My answer here does not apply, since UPDLOCK within different transactions should indeed work as OP expects.)

UPDLOCK does not prevent other sessions from reading, only from updating. And it seems there's actually no way around this using hints or isolation levels.

You might be able to accomplish what you're attempting by actually updating the row with its current values to produce a lock, and updating again with the new values before committing the transaction. But there may be safer ways to do what you're aiming for.

Comment: As far as I know if two UPDLOCKS will be requested on a same row one will acquire it at a time. When the first SELECT will actually select a row with UPDLOCK another select with UPDLOCK won't be able to read or acquire a lock on the same row before the first transaction is commited. you are saying that UDPLOCK does not prevent other session from reading, that is correct but it prevents other sessions from reading if they also  are reading with UPDLOCK. so in my case both queries are reading data with UPDLOCK.

Comment: I'm terribly embarrassed...I assumed you had fallen into the sort of evidence misinterpretation that I sometimes do. It's certainly possible you've hit a rare SQL Server bug.

Are the transactions being opened and committed within the two stored procedures?

Comment: Yes, those quires plus the update that follows them all run in a same SQL transaction scope that is committed after the update. Outer two methods are not run in a same SQL transaction (when run one after another), but insides of both methods (Method1 and Method2) are.